# Does Kendo include a MVC framework, data handlers, etc?

Tags: kendo-ui

We are trying different JavaScript libraries. The one I just completed is Sencho Ext JS and it is pretty much everything. It has controls, a MVC framework, data handlers, etc. I'm diving into Kendo and it looks like it is mostly UI controls, working with JQuery.

Is this correct? And if so, for the MVC framework & data binding, is there any libraries that work best with Kendo?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI includes

- UI Widgets
- MVVM Framework (client-side)
- SPA Framework

It also has an [ASP.NET MVC Server Wrappers](http://www.kendoui.com/server-wrappers/mvc.aspx) available as an optional package (that is also an additional cost). This provides a .NET library that can be used to add server-side data paging, filtering, and sorting to your MVC controller actions. This works best if you are using Linq queries (or Entity Framework). It also provides a set of Razor functions that can generate the JavaScript to initialize Kendo UI widgets.

For an example of the MVC Server Wrappers in use, have a look at the Sales Hub sample project.

- [Sales Hub live site](http://kendouisaleshub.com/)
- [Sales Hub source code (GitHub)](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-saleshub-demo)

Though, to be honest, I recommend just using JavaScript to init the widgets instead of the Razor helper functions. However the `DataSourceRequest` and `DataSourceResponse` classes provided by the MVC server wrappers are very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will look at it Monday. My question however was on the JavaScript side. MVC for the .js model, views, & controllers. And for the datasource, our server is REST/JSON so an ASP.NET MVC example is problematic as it's a LOT more code than a Web API 2 server.

Comment: Ok, I've installed the Sales Hub sample. But I can't figure out what is going on. First, is there any documentation for it. The code has no comments so it's impossible to understand it. Second, it appears that most of the code is on the server side which means a LOT more communication between the client and server. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: There is a little bit of SalesHub documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/SalesHub/kendo-saleshub-intro but the point of that sample app is to demo the MVC helpers, which are mostly MVC Razor code that generates the appropriate JavaScript to send to the client. Things don't have to be done that way, but your original question mentioned MVC, so I wanted to mention that it exists. I prefer to just write the JavaScript, of which there are other examples. For example the Kendo Music Store: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/kendo-music-store-intro